# Get values from array POST inside line

Tags: php, arrays, post, explode

I have great problem because i need fiz this and i don´t know how i can do it

I have simple line of Data separated by "," and this data are differents, all data in the same line as this :

```
$data_1="orange";
$data_2="yellow";
$data_3="".$_POST['options']."";
$data_4="".$_POST['street']."";
$data_5="Jhon";

$data_total="".$data_1.",".$data_2.",".$data_3.",".$data_4.",".$data_5."";
```

How you can see all these Data go inside the same line $data_total, and easy for process using explode for get different values, my only problem it´s with values i get from $_POST when are Arrays, for example from fields as multiple select with 3 , 4 or more values send from this field

Yes i can use explode, and show results, but when for example POST it´s array of values, only get the word Array.

Try process result :

```
$explore=explode(",",$data_total);

    $dt=0;
    foreach($explore as $explores)
    {
    
    print "DATA ".$dt." - ".$explores."<br>";
    
    /// But when loop for example number 3 only show word Array the question how show data inside Array from POST
    
    
    $dt++;
    }
```

My question it´s, how can show or extract the data from POST fields with array values, inside loop when explode line $data_total

I want get results as this for example:

```
orange
yellow
Result array content from $_POST['options']
Result simple content $_POST['street']
Jhon
```

Comment: Try with `$data_4 = $_POST['street'];`

Comment: Don´t understand you

Comment: I meant to try settings `$data_4` without joining it with empty strings (those empty quotes you have around `$_POST['street']`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly `$_POST['options']` is an array and you want to save it to `$data_3` to be used later but since it's an array it just prints "Array".

So you need to somehow convert array to string e.g.

```
$data_3 = implode(' ', $_POST['options']);
```

This will join all options with space between them and save it to `$data_3`